# Proving that a recursive sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, recursion

The sequence is defined as $ x_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{3^{k}}  $

I have re-written the sequence like so:

$x_{1} = \frac{1}{3} $ and $ x_{n} = \frac{1}{3^{n}} + x_{n-1}$

Now it's easier to work with it recursively. I believe I have proved that it increases by induction. I have proposed an upper bound of 2, but can't seem to show through induction that $ \forall n $ we get $ x_{n} < 2 $

Can someone how this is done. I haven't huge practice in working with recursive sequences. Thanks a lot !

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: Any particular reason you are choosing to view this sequence recursively? The infinite sum $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$$ converges quite nicely for all $x$ where $|x|<1$

Comment: I thought it might be easier. Am I over-complicating it?

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to prove an inequality like this inductively. It's much easier to write down a couple of sequence elements, guess how $x_n$ can be written in a closed expression and then prove equality to this closed expression inductively:

$x_1=\frac13$,
$x_2=\frac49$,
$x_3=\frac{13}{27}$,
$x_4=\frac{40}{81}$,
$x_5=\frac{121}{243}$,
$\ldots$

If you won't (or can't) use the formula for geometric sums that's the way to go.